# How to update column with the data from the columns in the same row in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table house with fields price and area, now I want to add one more column named 'average_price'.

How could I set the average_price according to the price and area in MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one idea:

- Add your column in your favorite editor/method
- Loop through your table and define average_price value
- Update actual row with your value

  `UPDATE your_table SET average_price = price/area;`

Comment: @fabrik: is this possible with one-line sql query?

Comment: It depends. What is average_price? If you can define it in a query i think it's possible of course.

Comment: @fabrik: average_price is equal to price/area.

Comment: @fabrik: it works well, amazing.I thought it would be much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a suquery. But I don't know about performance.

```
UPDATE `houses` AS h
SET `avg_price` = (
    SELECT AVG(`price`)
    FROM `houses` AS h2
    WHERE h2.area == h.area
)
```

Or you could create a temporary table in which to put the average prices and then update.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like the kind of data you should actually store, by how often you'd have to update it - once every single time you modify the house table in any way! That's a lot of unnecessary load on the database, and a whole lot of room for human error.

Instead, I recommend acquiring it on the fly through a SQL query when you need it, and never actually storing it.

Retrieving from all areas:

```
SELECT `area`, AVG(`price`) AS `average_price`
FROM `house`
GROUP BY `area`
ORDER BY `average_price` ASC
```

Retrieving from a specific area:

```
SELECT `area`, AVG(`price`) AS `average_price`
FROM `house`
WHERE `area` = "New York"
GROUP BY `area`
```

Comment: I have never thought about the update isssue before, vote up for your advice.

Comment: Thanks. :) As a rule of thumb, data derived from other data should generally be calculated in a query and not stored